# Can't add record to DB through nav collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Hello I have like this 2 tables

```
class User
public int UserId{get;set;}
{
....
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
...
}
class Product
{
public int ProductId{get;set}
..
public virtual User User;
...
}
```

I have set by Fluent Api like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithOptional();
```

I tried to add created product to navigation collection like this:

```
    if (user.Products == null)
        user.Products = new Collection<Product>();
    user.Products.Add(product);
    crud.Update(user.UserId, user);
```

When I am debuging I see that product has added to collection but didn't add to database
Please help me!If need I have more information about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//...
user.Products.Add(product);
modelBuilder.SaveChanges();  //modelBuilder is the dbcontext
```

Comment: Hi!thaks for post but SaveChanges is calling in Update Method(Crud)
              context.Entry(clone).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();